# Forwarding port 80 to 8080 using NGINX

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy, debian

I'm using LEMP stack and Node JS on my debian server. Nginx works on port 80 and Node JS on 8080. I created new subdomain: cdn.domain.com for nodejs app. Currently I can access to Node JS application only like cdn.domain.com:8080/. What I want to do is to configure Nginx so that, when I enter to cdn.domain.com I can get app working on port 80. I think it can be done using nginx upstream. But I can't figure out how.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 71):

As simple as like this,

make sure to change example.com to your domain (or IP), and 8080 to your Node.js application port:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         "http://127.0.0.1:8080";
    }
}
```

Source: https://eladnava.com/binding-nodejs-port-80-using-nginx/

Comment: Hi, with this solution, would I need to open port 8080 to outside or it is enough with port 80 open. Thanks

Comment: No need to open port 8080 or any other port. opening 80 only is enough.

Comment: should it be in `nginx.conf`file?

Answer (score 23):

NGINX supports WebSockets by allowing a tunnel to be setup between a client and a backend server.  In order for NGINX to send the Upgrade request from the client to the backend server, Upgrade and Connection headers must be set explicitly.  For example:

```
# WebSocket proxying
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default         upgrade;
    ''              close;
}


server {
    listen 80;

    # The host name to respond to
    server_name cdn.domain.com;

    location / {
        # Backend nodejs server
        proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade     $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection  $connection_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Source: http://nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/

Comment: The question is not about websocket, only HTTP.

Answer (score 11):

you can do this very easy by using following in `sudo vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name _ your_domain;

    location /health {
            access_log off;
            return 200 "healthy\n";
    }

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080; 
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 9):

Simple is:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  p3000;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3000;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvote for including `/etc/nginx/proxy_params` that is obviously meant to be used. You could make this answer more clear by using `cdn.domain.com` instead of `p3000`. But this works great in my case, I wonder why all the other answers suggest the use of `upstream` (will have to check that out now…).

Comment: @sylbru because with an upstream, you can easily load-balance the traffic

Answer (score 8):

This is how you can achieve this.

```
upstream {
    nodeapp 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    # The host name to respond to
    server_name cdn.domain.com;

    location /(.*) {
        proxy_pass http://nodeapp/$1$is_args$args;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-Port $server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-Scheme $scheme;
    }
}
```

You can also use this configuration to load balance amongst multiple Node processes like so:

```
upstream {
    nodeapp 127.0.0.1:8081;
    nodeapp 127.0.0.1:8082;
    nodeapp 127.0.0.1:8083;
}
```

Where you are running your node server on ports 8081, 8082 and 8083 in separate processes. Nginx will easily load balance your traffic amongst these server processes.

Comment: Looks like **upstream** does not work in latest nginx, such as 1.4.6.

Comment: I think the syntax is different: upstream name { server ... }

Answer (score 4):

You can define an upstream and use it in proxy_pass

http://rohanambasta.blogspot.com/2016/02/redirect-nginx-request-to-upstream.html

```
server {  
   listen        8082;

   location ~ /(.*) {  
       proxy_pass  test_server;  
       proxy_set_header Host $host;  
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;  
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;  
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;  
       proxy_redirect    off;  
   }  

}   

  upstream test_server  
     {  
         server test-server:8989  
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer. Users should be able to understand your suggestion without following a link offsite that may not work in the future.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
server {
  listen  80; 
  server_name example.com www.example.com;

  location / { 
    proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    proxy_set_header Host               $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;  
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

If it does not work for you look at the logs at `sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log`