# setup domain for django web server

Tags: django, dns, web-hosting

Say I have the domain `mydomain.com` and I want `www.mydomain.com` to display my Django site

I have looked at [the django docs](https://djangodeployment.readthedocs.io/en/latest/02-dns.html) but the answers they provide are confusing

what DNS records do I need to set to allow this? and are there any changes that have to be made to the config

note: I'm using ipv4 and am running ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are serving your project with the development server which runs on port 8000. You first need to run it with apache2 or nginx on port 80 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/), then set up your dns record to point to the ip address of your server

Answer (score 0):

You should make an A/AAAA record for the www subdomain that points to your server IP

Depending on the web-server you are using (for example Apache or Nginx) you can change the config to send traffic from the www subdomain to the Django server.

Comment: so how do I get it to use a port? because it runs on port 8000 and if i just use the IP address it doesn't work

Comment: That's where a web-server is needed. It can forward traffic (proxy) with a specific domain to a specific port of the machine.


For example nginx: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24861311/forwarding-port-80-to-8080-using-nginx