# How to set custom domain in Nexus Repo without port in URL

Tags: nginx, ssl, jetty, nexus, sonatype

I have installed Nexus Repo in my Ubuntu server, I was able resolve IP address to custom domain.

Now if I want to access the repo I would do the below

```
http://example.com:8081
```

I dont want to specify the port in the URL, I need to know, how can I use port 80 or 443 that browser defaults to.
Currently Port 80 is being used by nginx server. I tried changing the port of nginx to different port and then changed the nexus port to 80 but Nexus is throwing error and failed to bind to port 80 or 443.

Is there a way to do it? my nexus repo should open if I just provide my domain name

```
http://example.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

port 80 requires special permissions to allow a program to bind to it. (any port below 1024).

See: https://serverfault.com/a/112798

The above answer shows an IPTables solution.

Another thing you can do is just have nginx proxy requests to your nexus instance.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46067132/775715

Comment: See also here for specific instructions on setting up nginx or apache to run in front of Nexus Repo:  https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Run+Behind+a+Reverse+Proxy