# Unable to deploy due to an occupied port by running server

Tags: docker, nginx, github-actions, digital-ocean

I am using `digitalOcean` and deploying a simple `nodejs` app to a `droplet`.

It works fine. But I want to extend it to be able to add SSL certs and use same droplet to deploy multiple apps to different domains.

For that I am using `Nginx`. I have already installed `Nginx` on the droplet, added domain and SSL all working fine and running a simple html file on the main page `www.example.com`.

But how do I deploy my app now?

Getting the following error when I deploy now (using Github Actions) after installing `nginx`.

> Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address
> already in use.

What do I need to do so that I can deploy the node app to nginx? The domain and all the `nginx` configs been added according to this docs.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04

What am I missing. Do I need to stop/change something on the server?

Or update the Dockerfile or actions file?

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:20-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN yarn

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

Actions file

```
name: Deploy to DigitalOcean

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4.0.0

      - name: Set up Docker
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2.10.0

      - name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Build and push image to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4.2.1
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}/my-app:${{ github.sha }}
          build-args: |
            NODE_VERSION=20

      - name: Deploy to DigitalOcean Droplet
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v1.0.0
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.DROPLET_IP }}
          username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          port: 22
          script: |
            echo "Pulling Docker image..."
            docker pull ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}/my-app:${{ github.sha }}

            echo "Stopping and removing existing container (if it exists)..."
            if docker ps -a | grep -q "my-app-container"; then
              docker stop my-app-container
              docker rm my-app-container
            fi

            echo "Starting a new container..."
            docker run -d --name my-app-container -p 80:8080 ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}/my-app:${{ github.sha }}
```

Comment: _`-p 80:8080`_  you don't want to run your Node app on port 80. Run it on any old port (8080 is a good choice) and configure nginx to proxy requests through to it

Comment: @Phil For the 8080 config on the server end, do you mean this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46067132/2840178

Comment: Yeah, something like that. I don't know enough about deploying on Digital Ocean to be specific but that's the gist... nginx handles your HTTP / HTTPS traffic and proxies relevant requests through to your application